# Zend Framework 2 Doctrine Authentication logout inactive user

Tags: zend-framework2

I try to log out user after X minutes of being inactive.
But I cant find the way to setup session expiration time.
I use Doctrine 2 as authentication server/adpter.
I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to register all individual sessions a user has. The user can be logged in with different browsers at the same time. For every session, you need to register the time the user has started the session.

In some pseudo code:

```
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;

public function login($username, $password)
{
    // do some checks to perform the login
    // now you have a $user available if login is success

    // Session holds the session id and a timestamp
    $manager = new SessionManager;
    $id      = $manager->getId();

    $session = $this->registerSession($user, $id);
}
```

Then, you have to check at every request if the current session is not only available for php (the default login code), but also if the session is still valid according to your TTL (time-to-live). So, assume you get the logged in user with `getAuthenticatedUser()`, write something like this:

```
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;

public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{
    $manager = new Sessionmanager;

    // This is the session id
    $id = $manager->getId();

    // Now get the $session you registered earlier based on $id

    $now = new DateTime;
    if ($session->getTTL() > $now) {
         return false;
    }

    // continue and get $user based on $session
}
```